# how to select the closest next all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html content, which i cannot change:

```
<button class="out">out</button>
<div class="in">in1</div>
<div class="in">in2</div>
<div class="in">in3</div>


<button class="out">out</button>
<div class="in">in1</div>
<div class="in">in2</div>
<div class="in">in3</div>
<div class="in">in4</div>
<div class="in">in5</div>


<button class="out">out</button>
<div class="in">in1</div>
<div class="in">in2</div>
<div class="in">in3</div>
<div class="in">in4</div>
```

So what I should do is click the `out` button and then hide its content "below"

But they are with the same class, I dont know how to select them respectively.

Here is the fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph4h6/1/)

Comment: Where is you try/code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) in this context,

```
$('.out').click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.out').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uCvpK/)

And the following demo would guide you to how to toggle those elements,

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/uCvpK/1/)